# How could I prove that $n + n^2O (\ln n) = O ( n^2\ln n)$?

Tags: analysis, asymptotics

> How could I prove that $n + n^2O (\ln n) = O ( n^2\ln n)$?

I don't know how to handle the $n^2$ factor on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

If $g(n)\in O(\ln n)$, then for some $m\in\Bbb N,k>0$, we have $|g(n)|\le k\ln n$ for all $n\ge m$. Thus $|n^2g(n)|\le kn^2\ln n$ for all $n\ge m$, which gives $n^2g(n)\in O(n^2\ln n)$. Or concisely, $n^2 O(\ln  n)\subseteq O(n^2\ln n)$.

Similarly we can show that $O(n^2\ln n)\subseteq n^2O(\ln n)$ by observing that $|f(n)|\le k n^2\ln n$ implies $|f(n)/n^2|\le k\ln n$ for sufficiently large $n$, or $f(n)/n^2\in O(\ln n)$.

Can you complete?